# Under what circumstances can I not make a file world readble on linux

Tags: linux, chmod

I'm trying to set some files world readable

```
sudo chmod 664 *.ogg
```

however the files still have permission `-rw-rw----` after the operation.

These are phone calls recorded from Asterisk - if that helps at all.

Comment: Not sure what file structure you are using, so have a look here and see if this helps: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/chmod-won%27t-change-the-file-permissions-259218/

Comment: Doing `chmod -R 664` (recursively set the permissions) on the folder then `chmod 775` (set the permissions back on the folder only) on the folder seems to have solved this, although it is not the best solution

Comment: That is odd. Must have been a problem with the * extension. I was going to suggest a -R, but assumed you had more than just the .ogg files in your folder. Never mind you fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong command. `chown` is used to change the owner of a file. You are looking for `chmod`:

`sudo chmod 664 *.ogg`

As I am sure you are aware the above command will give you the following permission structure:

`-rw-rw-r--`

Comment: oops, you are correct - I've updated my question